# Solve 2D transcendental equations in R

Tags: r, transcendental-equation

How can I solve the transcendental equation for y, if I have the following two equations?

```
log(1 + 0.001 * (exp(y * xn) -1 )) == p0
log(1 + 0.001 * (exp(y * xm) -1 ) + p1) == pm
```

The values for the other variables are known:

```
xn <- 0.01
p0 <- 10
xm <- 1
pm <- 1000
p1 <- 200
```

Now I need to find the value for y, given the two equations.

Comment: You can get the solutions by algebra. The first equation rearranges to `y = log(1000 * (exp(p0) - 1) + 1)/xn` which is 1690.771. The second has no real-value solution - it rearranges to `y = log(1000 * (exp(pm) - p1 - 1) + 1)/xm`, which is infinite with the given parameters. You can use `optimize` if you don't want to use algebra, but the answers will be approximate - and will be essentially the same.

Comment: ah, my fault. The original formulas are `g * log(1 + 0.001 * (exp(y * xn) -1 )) == p0` and `g * log(1 + 0.001 * (exp(y * xn) -1 ) + p1) == pm`, where I need to eliminate g first to get y.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think I got it sorted.

First, eliminating g from the original equations rather gives this equation:

```
F(y) = pm / log(1 + 0.001 * (exp(y * xm) -1 ) + p1) - 
p0 / log(1 + 0.001 * (exp(y * xn) -1 ))
```

I then used the `rootSolve` package to get the root for y, like this:

```
fun <- function(y) {
  pm / (log(1 + c * (exp(y * xm) - 1) + p1) ) -
    p0 / (log(1 + c * (exp(y * xn) - 1)) )
}

curve(fun(y), 0, 500)
abline(h=0,lty=3)
d <- uniroot(fun,c(0,500), extendInt = "yes")$root
```